# Jquery background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to put a background image with Jquery, if the name of the image is something like: ../image(01).png, being that if I put the name in this way ../image01.png if it works, but not when it has parentheses the name of the image

Comment: No actual code samples, no idea. But I agree, sounds like you'll need to escape those parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `/image%2801%29.png`

That `percent+number` thing is called "percent-coding" and is a method to encode symbols for the URL, so 28 is `(` and 29 is `)` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) as well).

You didn't provide any code samples but I assume that that's the problem, considering what little information you provided. If it doesn't work please edit your question. Also, next time you should [google a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses) before you ask, and when you do ask always include the relevant code sample.

Comment: The problem is that when I load an image containing parentheses in its name it does not show it to me with the backgroud-image, but if the image does not have parentheses in its name it works correctly, I'm using a database to extract the names of the images so I can not change the names of them
its not working
$ ("#preview_front").css('background-image', 'url (../img/customcode/images/camaro-gt(07).png)');
it works correctly
$ ("#preview_front").css('background-image', 'url (../img/customcode/images/camaro-gt07.png)');

Comment: @Olbeng again, you need to escape the parenthesis. Try: `$("#preview_front").css('background-image', url('../img/customcode/images/camaro-gt%2807%29.png'))`. If you're loading the link from a DB you need to replace the parenthesis, i.e. `extractedString.replace('(', '%28')`

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like an URL encoding problem.